# Firebase Login - Loading stuck

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

My problem is that after completing the sign up or register form -the user is correctly showing in my Firebase- but the loading keep turning and do not go to the next page.

The form is like that : `LoginActivity.java` and then `menuPrincipal.java`

-or- , `profileRegistration.java`, `profileRegistration.java` and then `menuPrincipal.java`.

No error is showing in the code. The only weird thing is in the profileRegistration.java :

```
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressBarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        profileImageUrl =   taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    }
```

The .getDownloadUrl() is crossed, it says it's deprecated but it's not making any error.

Here is my `LoginActivity.java` :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener {

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
EditText emailLogin, passwordLogin;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    findViewById(R.id.signUp).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.logNow).setOnClickListener(this);

    emailLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
    passwordLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


}

private void userLogin() {

    String email = emailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passwordLogin.getText().toString().trim();

    if(email.isEmpty()) {
        emailLogin.setError("Email is required.");
        emailLogin.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //Ceci est pour check si l'adresse email est valide
    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        emailLogin.setError("Please Enter a valide email.");
        emailLogin.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //Ceci est pour vérifier si le champs du mot de passe est rempli
    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        passwordLogin.setError("Password is required");
        passwordLogin.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //Ceci est la condition du mot de passe qui doit être de plus de 6 caractères
    if (password.length()<6) {
        passwordLogin.setError("Minimum length of password is 6.");
        passwordLogin.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //Ceci est pour le gif loading pendant la création du compte
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Ceci permet de passer au Menu Principal une fois que le login est successful
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                     // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                    }
                      else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, menuPrincipal.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
 });


 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.signUp:

            startActivity(new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class));

            break;

        case R.id.logNow:
          userLogin();
          break;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the `RegistrationActivity.java` :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ProgressBar progressBar;
Button returnButton, doneRegister;
EditText emailRegister, passwordRegister;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);
    doneRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneRegister);
    emailRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailRegister);
    passwordRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordRegister);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    returnButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    findViewById(R.id.doneRegister).setOnClickListener(this);
    doneRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

//Ceci est si les champs email ou mot de passe ne sont pas remplis
private void doneReg(){

    String email = emailRegister.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passwordRegister.getText().toString().trim();

    if(email.isEmpty()) {
        emailRegister.setError("Email is required.");
        emailRegister.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //Ceci est pour check si l'adresse email est valide
    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        emailRegister.setError("Please Enter a valide email.");
        emailRegister.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //Ceci est pour vérifier si le champs du mot de passe est rempli
    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        passwordRegister.setError("Password is required");
        passwordRegister.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //Ceci est la condition du mot de passe qui doit être de plus de 6 caractères
    if (password.length()<6) {
        passwordRegister.setError("Minimum length of password is 6.");
        passwordRegister.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //Ceci est pour le gif loading pendant la création du compte
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Ceci est pour la création de nouveaux utilisateurs
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                //Ici, si l'inscription est successful on va arriver au profile
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, profileRegistration.class);
                //Cette ligne empêche de revenir au loginActivity
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                //Si l'utilisateur veux s'inscrire avec un email déjà existant
                if (task.getException()instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already register. Please log in.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

//Passer d'une activité à une autre
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){

//Retourner au Log normal, ceci est le bouton retour
        case R.id.returnButton:

         startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));

            break;

//Ceci est le bouton get started, il confirme le formulaire
            case R.id.doneRegister:

          doneReg();

            break;
    }
 }
}
```

And here is the `profileRegistration.java` :

```
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
 import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
 import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

 import java.io.IOException;

 public class profileRegistration extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE = 101;
ImageView pictureSelect;
EditText pseudoRegister;
Button saveProfil;

Uri uriProfileImage;
//ProgressBar progressBarImage;

String profileImageUrl;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_registration);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    pictureSelect = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureSelect);
    pseudoRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pseudoRegister);
    //progressBarImage = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarImage);
    saveProfil = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveProfile);


    //Dans ce OnClick on va appeler la méthode Action_GET_CONTENT
    pictureSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showImageChooser();
        }
    });


    findViewById(R.id.saveProfile).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveUserInformations();
        }

        });

    Intent intent = new Intent(profileRegistration.this,  LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, menuPrincipal.class));
    }
}



//Method pour enregistrer les info quand on clique sur DoneRegister
private void saveUserInformations() {

    String displayName = pseudoRegister.getText().toString();

    if(displayName.isEmpty()){
        pseudoRegister.setError("Pseudo is required");
        pseudoRegister.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(user!=null && profileImageUrl!=null){
        UserProfileChangeRequest profile = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(displayName)
                .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(profileImageUrl))
                .build();

        user.updateProfile(profile)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(profileRegistration.this, "Profile is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
 }

 //Clic droit, generate, override, Method to override to get the image from the chooserImage
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        uriProfileImage = data.getData();

        //Now we can select the image and display it
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uriProfileImage);
            pictureSelect.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            //Commande pour créer  la méthode pour stocker dans Firebase
            uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }


  //On va mettre la photo dans le cloud de Firebase
    private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(){
        StorageReference profilImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepics/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        if (uriProfileImage != null) {
            //progressBarImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profilImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            //progressBarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            profileImageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            //progressBarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(profileRegistration.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }


    }

//Méthode pour la selection de la photo
private void showImageChooser() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Profile Image"), CHOOSE_IMAGE);
 }

 }
```

I'm still new to this so I'm sorry if the problem is really obvious and I didn't see it. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your register should be:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(RegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In your `profileRegistration` you should call the `LoginActivity`

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
progressBarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
profileImageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
}
```

You need to add

```
Intent intent = new Intent(profileRegistration.this,  LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

In the **LoginActivity** should be

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUp);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logNow);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to answer ! I called the LoginActivity and added the Intent but it's still stuck. When I try to register or login, the progress bar just keep loading indefinitly.

Comment: can you please remove the progress bar to see if it is the problem?

Comment: also in which class the progress bar load infinitively?

Comment: I've take the progress bar out of all the Activities, and the Login or Register Activity still does not go to the next Activity

Comment: The progress Bar load indefinitly in both the LoginActivity and RegisterActivity

Comment: you say that the data is insert into db?

Comment: Yes, when I enter an email and password in the RegisterActivity.java it show up in Firebase. And when I try to put a wrong password in the LoginActivity, it says that this is a wrong password, so I think it is insert in th db

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate it, thank you, but I have an error on the second else ("else without if") for the LoginActivity

Comment: remove this `else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }`

Comment: Sorry, I've tried both Login and Register and it still won't display the next Activity

Comment: impossible,please update your question and let me see

Comment: It's possible I made a mistake, I've just updated my post with the actual Activities

Comment: why is this code?`Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.signUp:

            startActivity(new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class));

            break;

        case R.id.logNow:
          userLogin();
          break;
    }
  }`

Comment: and this????`findViewById(R.id.signUp).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.logNow).setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: `Button SignUpButton =findViewById(R.id.signUp);`then you do `SignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {...rest of the method`

Comment: findViewById(R.id.signUp).setOnClickListener(this); --> is id signUp si for the Button on the LoginActivity that leads to the RegisterActivity, and findViewById(R.id.logNow).setOnClickListener(this); is the id logNow is the Button on LoginActivity that confirm the login. And the public void onClick with the witch is to display the next activity. Ok, thank you, i'll try that!